# how to open outgoing port on centos 5.3?

Tags: ssh, centos

Iptables confuses me, can someone give me the command to open outgoing ssl connections from the server on port 443?

It's used by a script on the server, currently when I execute it on port 80 it works fine, on port 443 it just hangs so I'm assuming the ports not open for outgoing connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line in /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

And run command:

```
iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

presumably you have a script running on your own server that is making some connection to 1) a web server remotely, at either http port 80 or https on port 443 or 2) the script is connecting back to a web server running on the local server at port 80 or 443

By the sound of your description, "on port 443 it just hangs" you are able to make a TCP connection to port 443, but somehow the SSL protocol negotiation fails or some other problem occurs.

To test this you can do something like this from the command line;

```
# telnet www.yourservergoeshere.com 443
Trying 74.125.227.18...
Connected to www.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

and see whether it actually connects to the remote 443 port. If you get the message

`connected to www.someserver.com`

then the issue is not your iptables.

If so it is more likely to be what ever is in your script being unable to talk SSL/HTTPS

if the default INPUT rule for your iptables is DROP, then you might get your scripting waiting for the TCP timeout length before failing to connect.